# VBA Data Analysis Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm after a macro that can loop through a data table that i've prepared so that Excel can run multiple regressions at the same time using the "Data Analysis Tool pack"

So current my data table is set up so that every dependent variable is right before the subsequent independent variables im trying to measure against. Take for example the 3 types of dependent variables im trying to measure are: Sales, Revenue and Cost.
My dependent variables are A, B all through to Z.

My Example Table is set up as follows (See attached picture):

[Picture of Example Table set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjS1K.png)

I would like the macro to cycle through this table from Left to Right and generate a Regression Analysis output for every Dependent variable (Sales, Revenue, Cost) - i.e generate a result for Sales with A and B as independent variables, then perform same output below for Revenue with A, B and D, Then beneath that output do the same for Cost with H, Z and again for Sales with A, H, Z etc. etc.

Currently this is the code I have written out so far to generate the table. Note that the Dependent Variable will always be fixed and for this example assume the Dependent variable will always be Sales, Revenue and Cost.

```
Sub RunRegression()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, s1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Integer
Dim c As Integer, c1 As Integer, r As Long, lc2 As Integer, rng As Range, lr2 As Long, lc3 As Integer, i As Long


Set ws1 = Sheets("Data Table")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Regression name List")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Regression Table")
Set s1 = Sheets("Regression Test")


s1.Range("M30:M1000").Copy ws2.Range("A1")


'Remove all blank cells


ws2.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete


'clear regression table each run


Sheets("Regression Table").Cells.Clear


'create regression table from Data table to set up regression table to allow for regression to be peformed.


lr = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lc = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lc2 = ws3.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For r = 1 To lr
    For c = 1 To lc
        If ws2.Cells(r, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(1, c).Value Then
            ws1.Columns(c).Copy
            ws3.Cells(1, lc2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        lc2 = lc2 + 1

        End If

    Next c
Next r


' Example of a for loop used to cycle through and perform regression


'    For i = 1 To 3
'
'        Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", .Cells(1, .Column("C") + i).Resize(61), _
'        .Cells(1, .Column("AC") + i).Resize(61), False, True, , _
'        .Cells(109 + i * 20, .Column("C") + i), False, False, False, False, , False
'    Next i




End Sub
```

As i'm sure you are aware - one of the limitation with Excel is that it can only perform a regression on independent variables that are directly beside the dependent variable - which is why I had to create a macro to generate a table to assist excel in looping through and generating Regression analyses.

Comment: What's the problem with your code ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie
im not sure how i can make my code loop through the table and dynamically change the range based on when a dependent variable is next as we move left to right from the table. And also subsequently change the range of the independent variables such that it extends up until the next dependent variable is up then goes back one column. if that makes sense?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - When performing a regression analysis using the data analysis tookpack one of the limitations is that it requires all the independent variables to be in columns next to each other. I have created a table that sets up the information in that order. All i need is a for loop that can Cycle through the column headers and determine the range for the Dependent Variable (if it is 1 of three options) and then determine the range for the other independent variables beside it (Which will be the range of the NEXt Dependent variable minus 1)

Comment: so your question isn't about regression analysis etc - it is just about how to loop through ranges? It would be useful to update your question to reflect that.